# Space not released after deleting files - AIX Version 5.3

Tags: filesystems, aix

I have AIX Version 5.3. I have deleted some file from the file system but the space is not released.

The percentage of inodes in use is adequate.

Is there any permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 6):

Terminate the applications that are holding the files open.

Comment: I did the same, but can't restart the application again and again. Please suggest.

Comment: Please suggest what? That you rewrite the application?

Comment: If this is a log file, you might be able to send the process a signal such as SIGHUP, which it might understand as a signal to reopen any log files. If its something that was being spat our stdout and redirected to disk, you could send it to syslog instead (hopefullly you have a 'logger' command available, or if you have Apache available, it comes with a command (rotatelogs?) that writes its input to files, rotating as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that you deleted a file that was still opened by a process.

You can confirm which process is by the following commands:
lsof | grep -i "delete|name_of_your_file"
or
fuser -cu /filesystem/of/your/file

Be aware though, you won't have your space back until the process that was using the file is terminated.